# not understanding this java method, need explanation

Tags: java, android

```
private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
boolean qOpened = false;

try {
    releaseCameraAndPreview();
    mCamera = Camera.open(id);
    qOpened = (mCamera != null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return qOpened;    
}
```

in here... qOpened is equal to false.

but later here, qOpened is equal to (mCamera != null)

is it equal to false or is it equal to (mCamera != null) ?

and why do we need to declare "boolean qOpened = false;"? can't we just keep it to " boolean qOpened;"?

what difference would it make?

Comment: according to your question, it is too early for you start with Android. Read more about the language basics.

Answer (score 1):

`mCamera != null` itself returns a boolean result. Its a boolean comparison and the code line itself a replacement for:

```
if (mCamera != null)
   qOpened = true;
else
   qOpened = false;
```

About your question:

> and why do we need to declare "boolean qOpened = false;"?? can't we
>   just keep it to " boolean qOpened;"???

If there will be no `try/catch` clause it could be left uninitialised like

```
boolean qOpened;
```

But since `try/catch` maybe could fire BEFORE initialising `qOpened` (like in `releaseCameraAndPreview();`) Java won't know what to return in the end of method at

```
return qOpened;
```

Answer (score 1):

`mCamera != null` is a boolean expression that evaluates to either `true` or `false`. The result is then assigned to `qOpened`. The parentheses `()` around the expression are strictly not required but are there for clarity.

`boolean qOpened = false` is required to prevent a compile-time error about uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
qOpened = false;
```

doesn't mean `qOpened` is equal to `false`, it means *set* `qOpened` to be `false`.

It's an *assignment statement* rather than an equality.

So, in the code you've pasted, it's initially set to `false` then, assuming the call to `Camera.open()` doesn't cause an exception (if it does, the rest of the `try` block won't be executed), *and* it returns a valid value, it will be set to `true`.